# Why does the connection param of the closure need to be 'static bound?

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime, rust-diesel

The following code is invalid

```rust
pub async fn async_execute_in_transcation<T: AsyncConnection<Backend = Pg>>(
    connection: &mut T,
) -> Result<(), Error> {
    connection.transaction::<(), diesel::result::Error, _>(|conn| async {
        diesel::sql_query("insert into posts (title, body) values ('async_execute_in_transcation', 'async_execute_in_transcation body')")
        .execute(conn).await?;
        Ok(())
      }.scope_boxed()
   ).await?;
    Ok(())
}
```

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:15:67
   |
15 |       connection.transaction::<(), diesel::result::Error, _>(|conn| async {
   |  ___________________________________________________________________^
16 | |         diesel::sql_query("insert into posts (title, body) values ('async_execute_in_transcation', 'async_execute_in_transcation body')")
17 | |         .execute(conn).await?;
18 | |         Ok(())
19 | |       }.scope_boxed()
   | |_____________________^ ...so that the type `T` will meet its required lifetime bounds
   |
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...
   |
12 | pub async fn async_execute_in_transcation<T: AsyncConnection<Backend = Pg> + 'static>(
   |                                                                            +++++++++
```

I need to add 'static bound to the T generics or add a 'static lifetime annotation "connection: &'static mut T" to make it compile. Why?